# openbsd httpd fastcgi configuration

Tags: fastcgi, openbsd

How many fastcgi handlers can httpd configuration file have? I want to set up httpd server to server multiple fastcgi programs running on different tcp sockets.
For example: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/OpenBSDhttpd.html

```
server "default" {
    listen on 0.0.0.0 port 80

    fastcgi socket ":3031"
}
```

Is it possible to have another fastcgi program listening on 3032 , 3034 etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is **Yes, enough that you shouldn't need to worry.**

There is no apparent hardcoded limit. You can only have one `fastcgi` option per server or location block, but you can have *many* locations per server, like on the [example](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/OpenBSDhttpd.html) page you gave:

```
server "default" {
    listen on 0.0.0.0 port 80

    location "/foo/*" {
        fastcgi socket ":3031"
    }

    location "/cgi-bin/*" {
        fastcgi socket ":3032"
    }
}
```

While **[parse.y](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/usr.sbin/httpd/parse.y#L566)** cumulatively limits this as `INT_MAX`, in reality you will be limited to the number of file descriptors allowed/available per process *(including httpd's other tasks that need fd's)*

Comment: Thanks Pete! Appreciate your answer.